# PHP BBCODE Parser XSS

Tags: php, regex

At the moment I have this code, it works fine but if you start putting apostrophes etc in the url the [url] tag still displays the url with the apostrophe in it, I don't want the [url] or the [img] to work if there's apostrophes inside.

```
    $find = array(

    '~\[url=(.+)](.+)\[/url\]~s',   
    '~\[img\](https?://[^"\'><]*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s',

    );

    $replace = array(
    '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="$1">$2</a>',
    '<img src="$1" alt="Image"/>',
     );
```

Comment: What you've shown us is two arrays. How are they used? What is your input, and your desired and actual output?

Comment: function showBBcodes($text) {
}

I use a function like this, input is random text, [url=http://goo'gle.co.uk]A RANDOM LINK[/url], I dont want any apostrophes etc to be allowed in the urls

Comment: @Chris Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird sadly it did not

Comment: @Chris Can you update the question with the code that does not work and what should and should not match?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `(.*)` for the url,  use a negated character class `[^]'\r\n]+` where you don't match a `'`, a closing square bracket `]`.

You use the s modifier where a dot also matches a newline. If you don't want to match a newline for the url you could add `\r\n` as well.

You could change the second capturing group `(.*)` to a non greedy one `(.*?)`.

Your regex for the url could look like:

`~\[url=[^]\'\r\n]+](.+?)\[/url\]~s`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2aaYDw/1)